# Microsoft Word 2013 Template with Placeholders

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013

I need to create Microsoft Word document to be used as a template for generating other Microsoft Word documents based on template with placeholders replaced with actual values.

It must be like

```
Hello ##CUSTOMER_NAME##,

We want to offer you ##PRODUCT_NAME## for just $##PRODUCT_PRICE##
```

I know of document properties and "Insert\Quick Parts\Document Property". It is very close to what I want, except I have no idea how to add new property, because existing property set is not even close to my needs.

Comment: Two approaches off the top of my head.  One is mailmerge.  The other is {fields} (which can be used like variables in this manner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the mail merge feature in Word and select a data source. The data source can be another Word document, text file, Excel, Access, or any other data source that Windows (Admin Tools > Data Source) can process.

Press F1 in Word 2013 for Help. In the Help search screen, type "mail merge". There will be some steps and even videos on how to perform a mail merge.

There is also a Word for Dummies guide that will show how to perform mail merge as well:

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/computers-software/ms-office/Word/Word-2013/Mail-Merge.html

I am happy to provide steps, but since your question is very general, I will only provide exact steps if you state what your data source will be.